# Instant app related query

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

[Instant apps]

I am moving my playstore app to instant app format, can the user access the generated instant app URL?

I tried but still have certain doubts regarding the same.

could you please assist?

Comment: did you mean that u wants to create a URL that redirect to play store ? and open a download page of your xyz application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check google developers link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/ux-best-practices.html

Refer the details shared,
"Provide a way to share instant app URLs
Since instant apps don't provide an address bar for users to copy the URL, provide a "share" action within your app that allows users to share your instant app's URL."

Hope that helps:)